# Jquery requiring 2-3 clicks to execute

Tags: jquery

***Update:***
Thanks to everyone who has taken a look. I've ported the entire thing into JSFiddle so you can see what it's doing... http://jsfiddle.net/pJVbC/5/

***Background:***
I have a bunch of list items on a page, each of which has a dedicated button that triggers a copy of a URL (using zclip.) It works, but it requires 2-3 clicks in order for the jquery to fire. Any ideas why?

Here is the HTML...

```
    <dt>
  <div class="well">
    <div class="buttoncont">
      <button class="copybutton" prelink="http://www.MySite.com" postlink=""><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i></button>​
    </div>
    <h4><span class="name">MySite Home</span><br /></h4>
  </div>
</dt>
```

Here is the Javascript -

```
  <!-- Copy a static URL using zclip -->  
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $(".copybutton").click(function() {
          var prelink = $(this).attr("prelink");
          var postlink = $(this).attr("postlink");
          var link = prelink+postlink;
            $(this).zclip({
              path: "http://staging.mysite.com/hstoolkit/js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
              copy: link
            });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to your site? or maybe create a fiddle? Coz, I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: instead of using .click try using .live function  of jquery

Comment: **NO!** Do _not_ use `.live` as it's being deprecated. Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

this is the complete example. it is working perfectly for me. please check this one.if you problem solved,please vote me.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head runat="server">
                <title></title>

                <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.snippet.min.js"></script>


                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#copy-button").zclip({
                        path: "http://zeroclipboard.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10/trunk/ZeroClipboard.swf",
                        copy: function() {
                        var prelink = $(this).attr("prelink");
                        var postlink = $(this).attr("postlink");
                        var link = prelink + postlink;
                        return link;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>

            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <dt>
                    <div class="well">        
                        <div class="buttoncont">
                            <button id="copy-button" class="copybutton" prelink="http://www.MySite.com" postlink="">
                                <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                            </button>
                            ?
                        </div>
                        <h4>
                            <span class="name">MySite Home</span><br />
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </dt>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: i removed the asp.net tag. are you happy now ?

Comment: I agree with @Humayoo here in the sense that you don't have to attach it to a click, but rather initialize it to any item upon document load. The click works "by itself" on the overlayed SWF file.